# Why doesn't the C++/Java memory model include condition variables

Tags: java, c++, concurrency, java-memory-model, memory-model

I am referring to the formal definition of C++11 memory model (Mark Batty et al.), which includes atomics, locks, relaxed memory models, but no formal definition on the behavior of condition variables. Similarly in Java Memory Model, there also is no definition on the wait() and notify() mechanisms. Why is that?

Comment: Java spec has a tendency to leave implementation details up to the VM implementer.

Comment: @JornVernee But wait(),notify() operations are fundamental synchronization primitives, they directly affects 4 out of 6 of the java thread states (runnable, blocked, waiting, timed waiting). The JMM aims to formally define the behavior of concurrent executions, how can it miss out this important part?

Comment: Conditional variables affects execution flow firstly but not a memory. Therefore the memory model does not consider them.

Comment: That behaviour is well defined in [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2).The memory model is an implementation detail of that behaviour. If you want to know exactly what it is, you have to look at a VM implementation.

Comment: Well in the case of the JMM, that is strictly about the behavior of reads and writes.  That is why it is called the *memory* model.

Comment: @JornVernee I am aware of the textual definition about wait() and notify(), but I am more concerned with the formal definitions, which is also in the spec (Section 17.4.2). It clearly defines a list of "inter-thread action", such as volatile read/writes, locking/unlocking of monitor, thread Join/Termination, etc. This list of inter-thread actions must be executed in a total order (synchronization order) among themselves, and in a partial order (happen-before order) among all actions. However, the wait/notify are not even considered as an action, which is very strange to me.

Comment: @Zefick Can you elaborate more, I don't quite understand?

Comment: @StephenC Are you saying that wait/notify don't have any guaranteed semantic and can block, or not block, capriciously?

Comment: @curiousguy - No.  I am saying that the Java Memory Model [JLS 17.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) specifies the memory model.  If you want to understand the behavior of `wait` / `notify`, you read [JLS 17.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2) and the javadocs for `Object`.  They say what you can and cannot rely on.  (Sure the two things are related ... but they are different parts of the spec.)

Comment: @StephenC I see, these methods aren't primitives, and are defined in term of primitives defined in the memory model?

Comment: They are primitive.  They are just defined in a different place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Similarly in Java Memory Model, there also is no definition on the wait() and notify() mechanisms. Why is that?

Because it is a memory model.  It models / specifies the behavior of memory read and memory write operations in a multi-threaded application.

Aspects of the behavior of `wait()` and `notify()` are (in a sense) *emergent* from the memory model. Calls to `wait()` and `notify()` must be with primitive mutexes.  That means that *lock* and *unlock* actions occur at specific points, and (in the case of `wait()`) they are specified as doing *unlock* and *lock* actions under certain circumstances.  Those actions are modeled in the memory model ... and this makes the emergent semantics of condition variables sound, provided that you stick with the recommended patterns for implementing them.

Other aspects of the `wait()` and `notify()` are specified in the JLS.  It is in the same chapter as the Memory Model.  But a different section.  17.2 rather than 17.4.  The rest of the behavior is defined in the javadoc.

Comment: Given the semantics of wait() and notify(), I am expecting rules saying that "Notify actions synchronizes with wait action and contribute to the happen before order".

Comment: Well such rules are unnecessary.  The behavior is emergent from the specification of `wait()` / `notify()` in terms of lock and unlock actions ... and what the memory model says about lock and unlock actions.

Comment: I see what you mean, since notify() must be called within critical section, and wait() does not unblock until the notifyer leaves critical sections. But then comes my confusion, consider three threads A,B,C. A blocks on wait(), B calls A.interrupt(), C calls notify(), both B and C races to signal A, if B happens first, A will throw IE, if C happens first, A will set intrpt flag. Shouldn't there be a happen before order between B and C's actions?

Comment: Now you are talking about behavior that is outside of the scope of the memory model.  Happens-before is about memory visibility ONLY.  Not general synchronization / scheduling. And yes, if you use two *different* notification mechanisms then the specs do not say what happens.  (I would *expect* a race condition.)  The real problem here is that if they did tightly specify this aspect (and other aspects of thread scheduling, etc) would the spec be implementable using native threads across multiple OS platforms?  Probably not!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be concerned over a detail of the C++ "model" which doesn't even include undefined behavior, the ability to destroy atomics, etc. The model is fundamentally unsound and meaningless, so why do you even bother?